# JQuery-UI datepicker getDate method

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Non-working code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker(
{ onSelect: function(dateText, dpo){  
  var selectedDate = dpo.getDate();
});
```

From the API, I see that I can use `var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );` in lieu of the non-working code I posted. The `onSelect` documentation states "The function receives the selected date as text and the datepickerinstance as parameters". If the date picker is one of the parameters, why is the above code incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inst` parameter of the [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) is an internal object that represent the current state of the datepicker. Normally you don't need to use it, you can use `this`, it refers to the original input field.

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

Code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, dpo) {
        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
        console.log(selectedDate)
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y3hR6/

Comment: Ok, I was trying to avoid the pointless overhead of calling $(this).datepicker("getDate")...

Comment: @KyleM It's simple to use $(this) it's not a great overhead, inst it's used for internal thing (eg. for plugins)